# Javascript Google Maps API - Marker doesn't show up

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

I have the following code in a separate .js file, but for some reason the maker doesn't show up when I load the page, only the map.

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', drawMap);  

//MAP

function drawMap() { 

    var myLatLong = new google.maps.LatLng(53.4680477, -2.2400482); 

        var mapOptions = {
            center: myLatLong, 
          zoom: 14 
        };
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), 
            mapOptions);
      }

//MARKERS

var marker = new google.maps.Marker( 
    {
        position: myLatLong, 
        map: map,
        title: "Marker"
    }
);

marker.setMap(map);
```

Comment: You have declared your marker outside the function.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

try this

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', drawMap);

//MAP

function drawMap() {

    var myLatLong = new google.maps.LatLng(53.4680477, -2.2400482);

    var mapOptions = {
        center: myLatLong,
        zoom: 14
    };
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),
    mapOptions);

    //MARKERS

    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: myLatLong,
        map: map,
        title: "Marker"
    });

    marker.setMap(map);
}
```

Comment: Please indent your code correctly when writing an answer. Further to that, you don't need to `setMap(map)` as `map: map` is already in the marker options.

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that **marker.setMap(map);** is added before maps is initialised.
Try the following:

```
function drawMap() {
  // init maps then add marker to map
  marker.setMap(map);
}
```

Heres an example provided from [Google developers doc](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/marker-simple)

```
function initialize() {
  var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-25.363882,131.044922);
  var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 4,
    center: myLatlng
  }
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);

  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: myLatlng,
      map: map,
      title: 'Hello World!'
  });
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

Hope this helps.